# Click event - returning id of the inner element

Tags: javascript, html

i have a div tag element and a couple of other elements inside it. I have on-click event set at div element, so that i can use its ID in my function. That works, but only if i click direct onto div element.

If i click direct on some of the other elements inside it, my function does not work because than i get id of the clicked tag. Is there any way that i can get divs id, no matter where i click on the div.

This is my code:

```
<a class="link" href="/userview/{{sendedId}}">
  <div id="{{item.user_id}}" class="user" on-click="showUser">
    <iron-image src$="{{item.social_accounts.0.profile_image}}"></iron-image>
    <span class="username">{{item.full_name}}</span>
    <br/>
    <span class="followers">{{item.social_accounts.0.followers}} followers</span>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: why not `on-click="showUser(item.user_id)"`? By the way, you should mention the framework you are using.

Comment: It doenst work like that, but thanks, i found the solution on some other place.

Answer (score 0):

I used event.currentTarget and it works like i want it.